# Phoenix: showing/hiding Html elements depending on the route

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to show the menu icon if we're not on the home page.
I know I need to use something like this:

```
<div class="header">
   <%= if page_path(@conn) === "/" do %>
     #  Do nothing
   <% else %>
     <%= render Myproject.SharedView, "menuButton.html" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

But this isn't working because `page_path (@conn)` is supposed to give us the route based on the controller action: `page_path (@conn, :index)` and not the requested route by the browser.
So my questions is: what's the simplest function to do it wright?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `request_path` from [Plug.Conn](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html):

```
<%= if @conn.request_path == "/" do %>
```

If you want to do it for an entire controller, you can use [Phoenix.Controller.controller_module/1](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#controller_module/1):

```
if Phoenix.Controller.controller_module(@conn) == MyApp.PageController do
```

For your original code, if your intention is to do nothing, either use `unless`:

```
<%= unless @conn.request_path == "/" do %>
```

or invert your logic:

```
<%= if @conn.request_path != "/" do %>
```

Comment: That's it...twice! I was just asking you about that because I knew it wasn't efficient but I'm still very week on Elixir. Thanks Gazler. Your help is truly appreciated!